# Obtaining variadic template non-type parameter through explicit class

Tags: templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

```
template <char... Cs>
struct safe_implicit_cast
{
    using T = std::conditional_t<is_decimal_number<Cs...>::value, float, int>; // awkward: algo<Cs...> often already provides is_number_X (irrelevant, copied from code)

    // note T is created derived from a sequence of std::conditional_t's. Only one provided for the sake of simplicity and easily readable code for this post.

    template <template<char...> class algo0, template<char...> class... algoS>
    static constexpr T value =
        algo_is_same< algo0, algo_null_type>::value
        ? static_cast<T>(translate<Cs...>::value)
        : safe_implicit_cast<algo0<Cs...>::value>::f(); // SFINAE
};
```

I have two questions about this code. First of all, I wondered whether there is a way to obtain the data held by the variadic parameter within `algo0`; in this case an updated version of `Cs...` char pack, stored in `value`.
Secondly, I noticed that when I change

```
: safe_implicit_cast<algo0<Cs...>::value>::f();
```

to

```
: safe_implicit_cast<algo0<Cs...>::value::value<algoS...>;
```

a compilation error is caused. It only errors when the template parameter is being added.

note: I do not have a clear definition of `translate<Cs...>` yet, and it could definitely be considered an algorithm, as the variadic template expects to deliver. However, I used this algorithm implicitly, because `static_cast<T>(x)` does obviously not compile with the assignment of a variadic template parameter pack, that is `Cs...`, to `x`.

EDIT: For the first problem I could try to create an explicit struct holding the relevant information, quite similar to `std::tuple`, but not holding types, but characters, so that the data can be obtained by

```
using T = char_tuple<Cs...>;
```

EDIT2: The second question tries to accomplish recursion, so that all the available algorithms are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't completely clear what do you want... but...

First.

For first problem, I suppose that is better, for you, modify `safe_implicit_cast` to receive a single `typename`

```
template <typename>
struct safe_implicit_cast;
```

and define a partial specialization, that receive a `std::integer_sequence` `char` based

```
template <char ... Cs>
struct safe_implicit_cast<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>>
 {
   // using T, constexpr T value, etc
 };
```

This way you can create a `type`, non a value, inside algos (`algo0`, `algoS...`), that is a `std::integer_sequence<char, Ds...>` (where `Ds...` is the modified `char` sequence) and the (recursive?) call for the following `safe_implicit_cast` become

```
safe_implicit_cast<typename algo0<Cs...>::type>
```

Second.

I don't understand your second question at all because I have no idea about what is `f()` and I don't understand why do you want write

```
safe_implicit_cast<algo0<Cs...>::value::value<algoS...>
```

where the first `value` is a `int` or a `float`

Maybe do you mean a recursive call to `value`, using other `algos...` ?

Maybe something (caution: not tested) as follows ?

```
safe_implicit_cast<typename algo0<Cs...>::type>::template value<algoS...>
```

Comment: The second question was indeed trying to accomplish recursion, so that all the algorithms would be used.